# Struts2 doubleselect - doubleOnchange not working

Tags: java, struts2

i have a doubleselect coded as below.

```
<s:doubleselect name="category" 
    label="Category and Sub-category" 
    list="{'Fruits','Vegetables'}" 
    doubleName="subcategory" 
    doubleList="top=='Fruits'?{'Apple','Orange'}:{'Cabbage','Carrot'}"
    onchange="javascript:alert('hello1');"
    doubleOnchange="javascript:alert('hello2');">
</s:doubleselect>
```

But, the doubleOnchange attribute is not working.
the javascript coded in doubleOnchange is not executing.

when we change the value in first select, the javascript in onchange
executes and user gets the alert 'hello1'.

but when we change the value in second select, the javascript
in doubleOnchange does not execute.

is there any solution or workaround for this?

i have included the following jar files in projectname/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder in Eclipse

```
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.8.jar
xwork-core-2.3.8.jar
```

thanks,

Comment: Seems like a not implemented feature. :) You can try to modify `doubleselect.ftl` template to make it work. You can copy `on` block from `optiontransferselect.ftl` template to `doubleselect` and see if that works.

Comment: thanks @Aleksandr M. please see my update below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to pointer given by [Aleksandr M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700321/aleksandr-m) I got below answer to my issue.

Copied template\simple into Java Resources\src folder under project in Eclipse and
modified select tag in template\simple.ftl as follows:

```
....
<select<#rt/>
        name="${parameters.doubleName?default("")?html}"<#rt/>
<#if parameters.disabled?default(false)>
        disabled="disabled"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.doubleTabindex??>
        tabindex="${parameters.doubleTabindex?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
........................
........................
<#if parameters.doubleOnchange??>
    onchange="${parameters.doubleOnchange?html}"
</#if>
        >
</select>
....
```

earlier the below code for doubleOnchange was missing.

```
<#if parameters.doubleOnchange??>
    onchange="${parameters.doubleOnchange?html}"
</#if>
```

this portion of the code was copied from optiontransferselect.ftl